# Returning a single large clob from a restful service in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there any way to return a clob as text (or file) without splitting into smaller pieces first?

I tried creating a `GET` handler with `PL/SQL` source that would just do this:

```sql
declare
  txt clob;
begin
  ...-- set clob
  htp.p(txt);
end;
```

But then I was getting the error `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`.

I then tried cutting the clob in smaller segments and calling `htp.p` multiple times, which worked, but I was wondering if there was a way to send the whole thing in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/w_htp.htm#ARPLS70603) states that `htp.p` and `htp.prn` take only VARCHAR2 so you're limited by the max size of a varchar2 and if the clob length exceeds that it will throw an error. This is what you can do:

Loop through the clob in 4k chunks and output using `htp.prn`. Avoid using `htp.p` in a loop because that generates a newline characters which could mess up the output, for example if you're generating json. It's also good practice to let the browser know what he's getting by setting the mime header.

```
DECLARE
  l_clob  CLOB;
  l_amt   INTEGER := 4000;
  l_pos   INTEGER := 1;
  l_buf   VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    owa_util.mime_header ('text/html', true);
    l_clob := '....';
    LOOP
        BEGIN
        dbms_lob.read(
                    l_clob,
                    l_amt,
                    l_pos,
                    l_buf
        );
        l_pos := l_pos + l_amt;
        -- need htp.prn since htp.p generates a newline char at the end.
        htp.prn(l_buf);
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            EXIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints about `htp.prn` and the content type header but the main question was if it's doable without looping.

Comment: Nope, just updated

Comment: Is there another way without the use of the `htp` package that can accept a large clob?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Others smarter than me might know. This is more an ORDS question than an apex question.

Comment: Thanks, if nobody else comes up with an answer for a single call for a large clob I will accept this answer. The header and prn tips have already been very useful.

Answer (score 1):

```php
APEX_UTIL.PRN (
 p_clob IN CLOB,
 p_escape IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE );
```